# Off-topic flag should have a drop down option for other stack sites

Tags: feature-request, migration, close-dialog

I have come across 2 questions that are off topic, but there is no option to select a site to which it actually belongs to. and always i have to select some other option other that off-topic and then explain which site.

Suggestion:
It would be better if we have general radio buttons as shown as now and other radio button which enables a drop down with all the stack sites.

- SE site 1
- SE site 2
- SE site 3
- SE site 4
- Other

on Selecting **other**

- SE site 1
- SE site 2
- SE site 3
- SE site 4
- **Other**

  `<drop down of all stack sites shown>`